Python Question regarding the pandas processing Excel
I need some help with the Python to make corrections in Excel:
Original Table



ArrivalDate
ArrivalTime




2024-01-01
2024-01-01 12:00:01 PM


2024-04-01
1990-01-00 12:01:00 PM


2024-03-01
12:03:15 AM


2024-01-01
1990-01-00


2024-04-01




Desired Table:



ArrivalDate
ArrivalTime




2024-01-01
2024-01-01 12:00:01 PM


2024-04-01
2024-04-01 12:01:00 PM


2024-03-01
2024-03-01 12:03:15 AM


2024-01-01
Missing Time


2024-04-01
Need more Info



So I used Pandas in Python to try to automate the process
The following is my code:
import pandas as pd

#Read the file
df = pd.read.excel(path/excelfile.xls)

#Covert into datetime format for processing
df[ArrivalDate] = pd.to_datetime(df['ArrivalDate'])

#For arrival time, keeping only the time component
df[ArrivalTime] = pd.to_datetime(df['ArrivalTime', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M, errors='coerce').dt.time

#Replace Dates in ArrivalTime with the Dates in ArrivalDate column
df[ArrivalTime] = df.apply(lambda row: pd.to_datetime(row['ArrivalDate'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + " " + row['ArrivalTime'].strftime('%H:%M")) if pd.notnull(row['ArrivalTime'])else None, axis=1)

print(df)

This help me generate the table, but there are still some problems:

The time format is displaying as 2024-04-01 21:01:00, although I defined the format as "%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M"

Some time started with 1990-01-00, the code can't recognize those dates and return NaT


How can I fix these problems?

Code
import pandas as pd

# time pattern to extract
pat = r'(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} (AM|PM)$)'

# Check 'ArrivalTime' column contains date pattern
cond = df['ArrivalTime'].str.contains(r'^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s*')

# date + time part from 'ArrivalTime'
df['ArrivalTime'] = df['ArrivalDate'].str.cat(
    df['ArrivalTime'].str.extract(pat)[0], sep=' '
).fillna(
    df['ArrivalTime'].mask(cond, 'Missing Time').mask(~cond, 'Need more Info')
) # fillna 'Missing Time' if value has date pattern, else 'Need...'

df:
  ArrivalDate             ArrivalTime
0  2024-01-01  2024-01-01 12:00:01 PM
1  2024-04-01  2024-04-01 12:01:00 PM
2  2024-03-01  2024-03-01 12:03:15 AM
3  2024-01-01            Missing Time
4  2024-04-01          Need more Info

Example Code
import pandas as pd
data = {"ArrivalDate": ["2024-01-01", "2024-04-01", "2024-03-01", "2024-01-01", "2024-04-01"], "ArrivalTime": ["2024-01-01 12:00:01 PM", "1990-01-00 12:01:00 PM", "12:03:15 AM", "1990-01-00", ""]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


df[ArrivalTime] = pd.to_datetime(df['ArrivalTime', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M, errors='coerce').dt.time

there is a syntax error in this line you need to close the square bracket
df[ArrivalTime] = pd.to_datetime(df['ArrivalTime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M, errors='coerce').dt.time


I looked into your Python code for processing the Excel file and made a few adjustments to handle the issues with date and time formats. Here's the updated code that should produce the desired table:
import pandas as pd
    
df = pd.read_excel('path/excelfile.xls')
    
    df['ArrivalDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ArrivalDate'], errors='coerce')
    
    def process_time(row):
        try:
            if pd.notnull(row['ArrivalTime']):
                try:
                    arrival_time = pd.to_datetime(row['ArrivalTime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p', errors='coerce')
                    if pd.isnull(arrival_time):
                        arrival_time = pd.to_datetime(row['ArrivalTime'], format='%I:%M:%S %p', errors='coerce')
                except ValueError:
                    arrival_time = pd.to_datetime(row['ArrivalTime'], format='%I:%M %p', errors='coerce')
                
                if pd.isnull(arrival_time):
                    return 'Need more Info'
                return row['ArrivalDate'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + ' ' + arrival_time.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p')
            else:
                return 'Missing Time'
        except:
            return 'Need more Info'
    
    df['ArrivalTime'] = df.apply(process_time, axis=1)
    
    print(df)

Explanation:

Reading the Excel File: Use pd.read_excel() to read the Excel file.
Processing the ArrivalDate: Convert ArrivalDate to datetime format
using pd.to_datetime().
Processing the ArrivalTime:

First, check if ArrivalTime is not null.
Attempt to parse ArrivalTime as a full datetime. If it fails, try parsing it as just the time part.
If parsing fails (e.g., invalid format), return 'Need more Info'.
If ArrivalTime is null, return 'Missing Time'.


Combining Date and Time: For valid times, combine the date from
ArrivalDate and the time component.

This should handle the various cases in your data and produce the desired output. Let me know if this works for you or if you need further assistance!

Please review the SO policy on AI-generated content.
